NextJs with Mongoose: Multiple Connection Errors
I'm having consistent problems using NextJs with MongoDB/Mongoose.
Unhandled Rejection: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 45000 ms
    at Topology.selectServer (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:303:38)

Unhandled Rejection: MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:358:20)

My Setup:

NextJs 15

MongoDB and Mongoose

Hosting on Vercel

NextAuth


I have two connection files, one is only for the MongoDB Adapter for NextAuth, the other one is used for everything else.
// mongodb.ts for nextAuth
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  maxPoolSize: 10,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 45000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
  // Force IPv4
  family: 4,
};

let client: MongoClient;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  const globalWithMongo = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise?: Promise<MongoClient>;
  };

  if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', err);
        throw err;
      });
  }
  clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise;

} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect()
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', err);
      throw err;
    });

}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise
export default clientPromise;

// mongoose.ts for everything else
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your MONGODB_URI to .env.local');
}

const MONGODB_URI: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

interface MongooseCache {
  conn: typeof mongoose | null;
  promise: Promise<typeof mongoose> | null;
}

let cached = (global as any).mongoose as MongooseCache; // eslint-disable-line

if (!cached) {
  cached = (global as any).mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }; // eslint-disable-line
}

const opts = {
  bufferCommands: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
  maxPoolSize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 50 : 10,
  retryWrites: true,
};

async function connectToMongoDB() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn; // Return cached connection if available
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    try {
      console.log('MongoDB connection: Creating a new connection');
      cached.conn = await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts);;
    } catch (initialError) {
      console.error('Initial MongoDB connection error:', initialError);

      // Immediate retry before entering the delayed retry loop
      try {
        console.log('Immediate retrying MongoDB connection');
        cached.conn = await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts);
        return cached.conn;
      } catch (immediateRetryError) {
        console.error('Immediate retry failed:', immediateRetryError);
        cached.promise = null; // Reset promise for further retries

        // Retry logic with delays
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          try {
            console.log(`Retrying MongoDB connection, attempt ${i + 1}`);
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000 * (i + 1))); // Backoff delay
            cached.conn = await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts);
            return cached.conn;
          } catch (retryError) {
            console.error(`Retry ${i + 1} failed:`, retryError);
            if (i === 2) {
              throw retryError; // Throw on final retry
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return cached.conn;
}


export default connectToMongoDB;

export async function closeMongoDBConnection() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    try {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      cached.conn = null;
      cached.promise = null;
      console.log("MongoDB connection closed successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error closing MongoDB connection:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

To see which one is responsible for the one error, I used different options and the mongodb.ts seems to be the issue for one.
In this mongoose article I have seen that the problem might be the edge runtime. Is this true and how can I fix this? Has anyone else faced the same problems?
I was also trying to integrate mongoDB Atlas into Vercel, but it loads for ages.
Thanks in advance!
So far I have tried to localize which DB Connector is at fault. Additionally, I have put await connectToMongoDB() before every db request - this has not fixed the issue unfortunately. Next thing I wanted to try was to put export const runtime = 'nodejs' in the outer layout.tsx.
